# iAd interstitial after UIWebView did finish load

Tags: ios, ipad, iad, interstitial

I want to show an iAd interstitial only once after `webViewdidFinishLoad` is called.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [self cycleInterstitial];
        [self performSelector:@selector(presentInterlude) withObject:nil afterDelay:300]; 
    }
}

-(void)cycleInterstitial {
    // Clean up the old interstitial...
    interstitial.delegate = nil;
    // and create a new interstitial. We set the delegate so that we can be notified of when
    interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
    interstitial.delegate = self;
}

-(void)presentInterlude {
    // If the interstitial managed to load, then we'll present it now.
    if (interstitial.loaded) {
        NSLog(@"Loaded inter");
        [interstitial presentFromViewController:self];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not Loaded inter");   
    }
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    [self cycleInterstitial];
}

-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"interstitialAd error: %@",error.description);
}
```

This works but I want to only show one iAd interstitial after `webViewdidfinishload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply accomplished by setting up a `BOOL` to check if the `ADInterstitialAd` has already been shown.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    BOOL doNotShowAd;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad  && doNotShowAd == NO) {
        [self cycleInterstitial];
        [self performSelector:@selector(presentInterlude) withObject:nil afterDelay:300];
        doNotShowAd = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is right. I want present directly an ADInterstitialAd if the user open the App and after 300s present a new ADInterstitialAd and if the user close the App(home Button) for a long time and open it again an AdInterstitialAd comes and the 300s restarted. And who set i the doNotShowAd = NO; ? Or didn't i need this?

Comment: and how can i do? if i close the App without Termination and i called the App to foreground than gave me a new full iAdInterstitial?